# Trying to make total color of image, not good at programming

Tags: hex, color-picker, color-palette, colormap

I'm working on a spectroscopy project though its taking way too long. I haven't found any program online that can do what I need and I don't know how to do it myself. What I need is a program that takes an image(from the hard drive) and adds the rgb values in DEC out of 255 of every pixel, returned individually in red, green, and blue. Additionally, although I can do this part on my own, the values then need to be multiplied by 255 divided by the greatest value and converted to HEX as to retrieve a kinda total color of the entire image. (NOTE: I do not want an average color of the image, I tried that and it only returns neutral colors)

Answer (score 0):

By googling for 2 minutes I found this:

https://itg.beckman.illinois.edu/technology_development/software_development/get_rgb/

No idea if it works but it looks like it does what you want.